# How to return data using map function in Next js or React js when you want to return a json's object and access it's key one by one

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, next.js, jsx

I have a json file imported like this

```
import Register from '@data/json/register.json';
```

from which an object is being selected considering the URL params (in this case 'http://localhost:3000/register/basketball' => 'basketball'.

```
const [RegisterList, setRegisterList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < Register.length; i++) {
            if (Register[i].SportsName === params.sport.toLowerCase()) {
                setRegisterList([Register[i]]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }, [])
```

The json that RegisterList now contain is :

```
{
    "SportsName": "basketball",
    "College Name": 1,
    "Team Name": 1,
    "Captian Name": 1,
    "Full Name": 0,
    "Contact Number": 1,
    "Duo/Team": 0,
    "Course Name": 1,
    "Year": 1,
    "Sem": 0,
    "Student ID": 0,
    "Player": 5,
    " Screenshot of Payment ": 1
}
```

Next I want to check whether these key's value is true or false (1 or 0) and decided if map function will pass it or not in this FormBox.

```
<FormBox parameter={'College Name'} />
<FormBox parameter={'Team Name'} />
<FormBox parameter={'Team Captain'} />
<FormBox parameter={'Contact Number'} />
<FormBox parameter={'Screenshot of Payment'} />
```

I tried a lot but the I can't seems to get the key's of this object one by one like I can get if it's an array, suppose I don't know what the keys are, what I want to achieve is that **I want to check value of each key and if its 1 then I want to return FormBox with parameter as the key with value 1**
I am open for any other way to do this but still if you can help me find a way this way it would be sweet.

For reference I will give out all the code here:

@app/register/[sport]/page.jsx

```
"use client";
import FormBox from '@components/FormBox';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Register from '@data/json/register.json';
function RegistrationForm({params}) {
    const [RegisterList, setRegisterList] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < Register.length; i++) {
            if (Register[i].SportsName === params.sport.toLowerCase()) {
                setRegisterList([Register[i]]);
                console.log(RegisterList);
                break;
            }
        }
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
        <main className='flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center relative z-10'>
        <h3 className='text-2xl font-bold  w-full text-center sm:text-3xl texts'>{params.sport.toUpperCase()} Tournament Registration Form</h3>
        <form id='form-box' className="bg-yellow-200 py-10 rounded-2xl m-5 w-[calc(100%-2.5rem)] bg-opacity-30 max-w-3xl">
        {RegisterList.map((item, index) => {
            console.log(item);
        })}
            <FormBox parameter={'College Name'} />
            <FormBox parameter={'Team Name'} />
            <FormBox parameter={'Team Captain'} />
            <FormBox parameter={'Contact Number'} />
            <FormBox parameter={' Screenshot of Payment'} />
            <div className="w-full flex justify-center items-center h-16"><button className="form-box bg-white h-12 px-4 rounded-2xl border-yellow-200 active:bg-yellow-500 hover:border-yellow-400 border-4" type="submit">Submit</button></div>
        </form>
        </main>
    </>
    );
}

export default RegistrationForm;
```

@data/json/register.json

```
[
    {
        "SportsName": "volleyball",
        "College Name": 0,
        "Team Name": 1,
        "Captian Name": 1,
        "Full Name": 0,
        "Contact Number": 1,
        "Duo/Team": 0,
        "Course Name": 1,
        "Year": 1,
        "Sem": 0,
        "Student ID": 1,
        "Player": 7,
        " Screenshot of Payment ": 1
    },
    {
        "SportsName": "cricket",
        "College Name": 1,
        "Team Name": 1,
        "Captian Name": 1,
        "Full Name": 0,
        "Contact Number": 1,
        "Duo/Team": 0,
        "Course Name": 1,
        "Year": 1,
        "Sem": 0,
        "Student ID": 0,
        "Player": 11,
        " Screenshot of Payment ": 1
    },
    {
        "SportsName": "basketball",
        "College Name": 1,
        "Team Name": 1,
        "Captian Name": 1,
        "Full Name": 0,
        "Contact Number": 1,
        "Duo/Team": 0,
        "Course Name": 1,
        "Year": 1,
        "Sem": 0,
        "Student ID": 0,
        "Player": 5,
        " Screenshot of Payment ": 1
    },
    {
        "SportsName": "chess",
        "College Name": 0,
        "Team Name": 0,
        "Captian Name": 0,
        "Full Name": 1,
        "Contact Number": 1,
        "Duo/Team": 0,
        "Course Name": 1,
        "Year": 1,
        "Sem": 0,
        "Student ID": 0,
        "Player": 0,
        " Screenshot of Payment ": 1
    },
    {
        "SportsName": "carrom",
        "College Name": 0,
        "Team Name": 0,
        "Captian Name": 0,
        "Full Name": 1,
        "Contact Number": 1,
        "Duo/Team": 0,
        "Course Name": 1,
        "Year": 1,
        "Sem": 0,
        "Student ID": 0,
        "Player": 0,
        " Screenshot of Payment ": 1
    },
    {
        "SportsName": "badminton",
        "College Name": 0,
        "Team Name": 0,
        "Captian Name": 0,
        "Full Name": 1,
        "Contact Number": 1,
        "Duo/Team": 1,
        "Course Name": 1,
        "Year": 1,
        "Sem": 0,
        "Student ID": 0,
        "Player": 1,
        " Screenshot of Payment ": 1
    },
    {
        "SportsName": "table tennis",
        "College Name": 0,
        "Team Name": 0,
        "Captian Name": 0,
        "Full Name": 1,
        "Contact Number": 1,
        "Duo/Team": 1,
        "Course Name": 1,
        "Year": 1,
        "Sem": 0,
        "Student ID": 0,
        "Player": 1,
        " Screenshot of Payment ": 1
    }
]
```

@components/FormBox

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
const FormBox = (params) => {
  if (params.parameter === ' Screenshot of Payment') {
    return <FormImage parameter={params.parameter} />
  }
  else if (params.parameter === 'Contact Number') {
    return <FormPhone parameter={params.parameter} />
  }
  else {
    return <FormInput parameter={params.parameter} />
  }
}
const FormInput = (params) => {
  return (
  <div className='flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center mb-5 sm:justify-start sm:m-10'>
    <label className='w-full font-bold px-2 text-center sm:text-left sm:text-2xl' htmlFor={params.parameter.replace(/\s/g, "")}>{params.parameter}:</label>
    <input className='form-box h-7 px-2 rounded w-8/12 sm:mx-2 sm:w-full' type="text" id={params.parameter.replace(/\s/g, "")} required />
  </div>
  )
}

const FormImage = (params) => {
  const [screenshot, setScreenshot] = useState(null);
    const handleScreenshotChange = (event) => {
    setScreenshot(event.target.files[0]);
  };
  return (
  <div className='flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center mb-5 sm:justify-start sm:m-10'>
    <label className='w-full font-bold px-2 text-center sm:text-left sm:text-2xl' htmlFor="screenshot">{params.parameter}:</label>
    <input className='form-box sr-only' type="file" id="screenshot" accept="image/*" onChange={handleScreenshotChange} required />
    <div className='w-full m-2'>
      {screenshot
      ?<>
      <img className='w-full' src={URL.createObjectURL(screenshot)} alt="Screenshot" />
      <div onClick={()=>{document.getElementById('screenshot').click()}} className='cursor-pointer hover:underline float-left'>Change Image</div>
      <div onClick={()=> {setScreenshot(null)}} className='cursor-pointer hover:underline float-right'>Remove Image</div>
      </>:
      <div className='flex justify-center w-full'><span onClick={()=>{document.getElementById('screenshot').click()}} className="cursor-pointer form-box px-4 py-1 rounded text-white border-2 border-white bg-yellow-300">Click Here To Upload</span></div>
      }
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}

const FormPhone = (params) => {
  return (
  <div className='flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center mb-5 sm:justify-start sm:m-10'>
    <label className='w-full font-bold px-2 text-center sm:text-left sm:text-2xl' htmlFor="contactNumber">{params.parameter}:</label>
    <input className='form-box h-7 px-2 rounded w-8/12 sm:mx-2 sm:w-full' type="tel" id="contactNumber" required />
  </div>
  )
}
export default FormBox;
```

Passing an objects give me error of .map is not function then I tried to make it an array but lost the json attribute and can't access keys like I can do in array.

Comment: `Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the object to array you should use `Object.entries(object)`

**How it works**

```
const data= {
    "SportsName": "basketball",
    "College Name": 1,
    "Team Name": 1,
};
const arr = Object.entries(data);
console.log(arr);

/** Output:
[ [ 'SportsName', 'basketball' ],
  [ 'College Name', 1 ],
  [ 'Team Name', 1 ]
]
**/
```

**Then to loop over object**

```
Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
// do something
}
```